# what is the difference between ,(comma) and and in group by?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I want to find number of student taken classes of every subject semester wise.
Below is the query which gives right answer

```
select semester,subject,count(stdId) 
from tblSubjectMaster 
group by subject, semester
```

But I have tried also other query and It is giving different result. Query is

```
select semester,subject,count(stdId) 
from tblSubjectMaster
group by subject and semester
```

what is the difference between , and and in group by?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comma separates expressions. `group by subject, semester` is creating a separate group for each distinct pair of values. I think that's what you want.

The example using `AND` is only one boolean expression, with only two distinct groups, one for **true** and one for **false**. `AND` is a boolean operator. It evaluates its two operands and then gives the boolean conjunction between them.

So it evaluates both `subject` and `semester` as booleans only, and then if both are true, then the whole boolean expression is true. That's the way a boolean `AND` works.

MySQL treats booleans as the same thing as integer values 1 for true and 0 for false. So it will evaluate `subject` and `semester` as numbers. This may give unexpected results.

You should use the comma if you want to group by two columns.

Answer (score 3):

`GROUP BY subject, semester` means to create a row in the result set for each unique combination of `subject` and `semester`, with the count of rows with that combination.

`subject and semester` is a logical expression, it's `TRUE` if both `subject` and `semester` are true, otherwise it returns `FALSE`. If the column contains strings, a non-empty value is true, an empty string is false; if the column contains a number, a non-zero value is true, zero is false.

So you'll get at most two rows in the result. One group for all the rows where both columns are true, and one row for all the others.

There's almost no use for `GROUP BY col1 AND col2`.